# How wait() works in main() method?

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety, wait, program-entry-point

I have created a main thread with two additional threads. When I use wait() in the main method with an object ( because wait() is an instance of the object and cannot be used directly in an instance of a class ) of one thread ( t1.wait() ). Both thread t1 and t2 finish executing before main resumes. The output is the same if I use t2.wait().

So, How does t1.wait() / t2.wait() actually work in the below code snippet?

```
class ThreadX implements Runnable {
    int count;
    Thread t;

    ThreadX() {
        t = new Thread(this);
    }

    public void run() {
        System.out.println("ThreadX Started");
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            count++;
        }
        synchronized (this) {
            notify();
        }
    }
}

class ThreadY implements Runnable {
    int count;
    Thread t;

    ThreadY() {
        t = new Thread(this);
    }

    public void run() {
        System.out.println("ThreadY Started");
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            count++;
        }
        synchronized (this) {
            notify();
        }
    }
}

public class MainThread {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        System.out.println("Main Thread");
        ThreadX t1 = new ThreadX();
        ThreadY t2 = new ThreadY();

        t1.t.start();
        t2.t.start();

        synchronized (t1) {
            t1.wait();
        }

        System.out.println(t1.count);
        System.out.println(t2.count);
    }
}
```

The below is the output,

```
Main Thread
ThreadX Started
ThreadY Started
10
100
```

Comment: To understand how `synchronzied` works, I recommend reading a tutorial on the topic, e.g. [this one from `oracle.com`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/sync.html). --- For the given use case, I would recommend using [`Thread::join`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Thread.html#join()) (on both threads). This fits the use case better and would simplify the program.

Comment: You're lucky that the main thread ever ended. If, by some chance, your `t1` thread had called `this.notify()` _before_ the main thread called `t1.wait()`, then the main thread would have been stuck forever. When you `notify()` some object, the object does not _remember_ that it was notified. A `notify()` call will wake a thread that already is waiting, but if no thread is waiting, then the `notify()` call does absolutely nothing at all.